# In-App Purchase in sandbox environment not authorized change via app store connect

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store

Similar to other stackoverflow posts, but itunes have since been deprecated, so many posts are irrelevant.

For Xcode 14.3, and nov 2023,
going here https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/users/sandbox

i dont know where to authorize my sandbox user.
I am using `<personalemail>+sandbox@gmail.com` as the sandbox apple Id. and apple pay is checked. Interrupted purchases is not checked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

fml i only signed into one place... you need to sign into two places.
didnt have anything to do with appstoreconnect.
the purchase shows my personal email, instead of sandbox. had to fix that.

1. iphone physical device > settings > profile > sign in to the sandbox account
2. iphone physical device > settings > App Store > Sandbox > sign in to the sandbox account.

other gotchas in my process:

1. sign the paid app agreements at appstoreconnect.apple.com > "agreements..." button
2. create a sandbox user that isnt your personal email. they wont allow you. maybe + works.